# LocationListener does not get killed

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I have a foreground service which implements LocationListener. When the Service is killed, it keeps on getting a fix. However this is what I call in the `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(getPackageName(), "Destroying GPSservice");
    super.onDestroy();
    running = false;
    stopForeground(true);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(EventService.this);
    locationManager = null;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

***EDIT***

More code. This is in the `onCreate()`:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            3000L, 15.0f, this);
```

Comment: add more info, how your locationListener is implemented?

Comment: I really don't want to sound snobby but: it's implemented like it should be. The GPS itself is working A-OK, but when the Service gets killed, I want the locationManager to remove the updates the Service has. Instead, it keeps on getting a fix. Otherwise, I have to copy past a LOT of code here..

Comment: post some more code to show how your location listener is implemented

Comment: Do you know if your `onDestroy()` method is being called? Do you have clients bound to your service?

Comment: I have a similar problem. In my case the issue has to do with the Activity lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle). Note how the activity can be killed without calling onDestroy, preventing the location listener from being registered.

Comment: Sorry, s/b "deregistered". Missed the 5 minute edit window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It turns out, the `MyLocationOverlay` binds to the LocationSensorThread too, and I was never turning that off. So that was keeping the GPS awake.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(Your_Location_Listener_instance);
```

instead of

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(EventService.this);
```

for more infromation see doc [public void removeUpdates (LocationListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29)

Comment: I have stated above that my LocationListener is implemented by the EventService. So that's my instance I think.